# NPM Install is broken

Tags: node.js, linux, git, npm, node-gyp

I have tried everything and persistent npm errors stop me doing a npm install please does anyone know how to fix and get rid of these errors to allow me to do a normal npm install.

> ````
> 21 verbose stack Error: spawn git ENOENT
> 21 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
> 21 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
> 21 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
> 22 verbose cwd /srv/daemon-data/c799c1b9-338f-41e8-bd64-35ce6d40e81a
> 23 verbose Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
> 24 verbose argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/npm" "install"
> 25 verbose node v12.14.0
> 26 verbose npm  v6.13.4
> 27 error code ENOENT
> 28 error syscall spawn git
> 29 error path git
> 30 error errno ENOENT
> 31 error enoent Error while executing:
> 31 error enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/mklabs/watchd.git
> 31 error enoent
> 31 error enoent
> 31 error enoent spawn git ENOENT
> 32 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> 33 verbose exit [ 1, true ]```
> ````

Anyone know how to fix this as some of you asked I have attached the package.json I am using for the npm install below hope this helps find a solution

> 

```
  "name": "udb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "bake-cli": "^0.1.6",
    "eslint": "^2.10.2",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^1.3.2",
    "mocha": "^2.5.2",
    "standard-version": "^2.2.1",
    "watchd": "github:mklabs/watchd"
  },
  "bake": {
    "description": "Scaffold a basic ES6 setup",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "echo Starting generation of default template",
      "prestart": "echo prestart",
      "poststart": "echo poststart",
      "install": "npm install --loglevel warn --cache-min Infinity",
      "preinstall": "echo Installing dependencies ...",
      "postinstall": "npm ls --depth 0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "better-sqlite3": "^5.4.3",
    "config-yml": "^0.10.3",
    "console-stamp": "^0.2.9",
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "enmap": "^5.2.2",
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    "google": "^2.1.0",
    "got": "^9.6.0",
    "lodash.sortby": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.5",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "opusscript": "^0.0.7",
    "quick.db": "^7.0.0-b22",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "strict-uri-encode": "^2.0.0",
    "weather-js": "^2.0.0",
    "ytdl-core": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

> 

Hopefully someone knows a fix and can help me solve this.

Comment: What is in the `package.json`? It looks like you are depending on a git repo over ssh, which requires auth.

Comment: better-sqlite3 and a some others but thats the one known to cause issues

Comment: That package is a file watcher. Maybe something in your dev deps. Search your project code (incl node_modules) for this string: `ssh://git@github.com/mklabs/watchd.git`

Comment: there isnt a single package with that string all are https

Comment: Do you have git in your path?

Comment: Can you please post your package.json file?

Comment: sure Ill post my package .json also what do you mean by git in my path ?

Answer (score 0):

`git` is not in your path

Your file log states:

`28 error syscall spawn git`

`29 error path git`